# Implementing a Game Tree for Checkers

Tags: c++, tree

I want to implement a game tree which can have any number of nodes at each level, basically i'm working on AI for checkers and i want to implement a game tree to be used in minimax algorithm.This is my code and i was working on the first case of insertion i.e when the Tree is empty....but when i try to access the data at root, my program crashes! any help?? :/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    Node **child;
    int data;
};

class Tree {
public:
    Node *root;
    Tree() {
        root = NULL;
    }

private:
    void add(Node *r, int data, int size) {
        if (r == NULL) {
            Node *newnode = new Node;
            newnode->child = new Node*[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                newnode->child[i] = new Node;
                newnode->child[i]->child = 0;
            }
            newnode->data = data;
            r = newnode;
        }
    }

public:
    void add(int data, int size) {
        add(root, data, size);
    }
};

int main() {

    Tree t;
    t.add(5, 20);
    cout << t.root->data << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your debugger can help.

Comment: I don't uderstand the structure of your add methods.  Why pass 'root' around inside them when it's a member var?

Comment: Recommend rethinking how you're doing this because you're coding your way into bug city. For example, how many children are in a given `Node`? That bit of information was discarded. You can only add to `root`. `Node` does not have proper ownership of child and counts on `Tree` to do the heavy lifting. This means `Tree` needs to know everything about itself and all the `Node`s, over complicating `Tree` and under complicating `Node`.

Comment: This is not the approach that's usually used for game play. The problem is that the tree is far too big to represent in memory. So the typical [minimax implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) generates moves on the fly and calls itself to evaluate each response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your private add function you pass r by value. So when you set  r = newnode you are in fact setting the address for a local pointer variable and it will not affect root. Here is the workaround:

```
class Tree {
public:
    Node *root;
    Tree() {
        root = NULL;
    }

private:
    void add(Node **r, int data, int size) {
        if (*r == NULL) {
            Node *newnode = new Node;
            newnode->child = new Node*[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                newnode->child[i] = new Node;
                newnode->child[i]->child = 0;
            }
            newnode->data = data;
            *r = newnode;
        }
    }

public:
    void add(int data, int size) {
        add(&root, data, size);
    }
};
```

Comment: Works, but recommend using a reference not a pointer `void add(Node *&r, int data, int size) {`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is:

```
r = newnode;
```

r is a local variable you must do

```
root = newnode;
```

And your code will work.

Hope this help